# Parsing and slicing char[] in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have the following code:

```
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

int iResult = recv(this->ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
if (iResult > 0) {
    printf("Message received: %s\n", recvbuf);
    std::string recvbuf = recvbuf;
    printf("Message as string: %s\n", recvbuf);
    std::string msg = recvbuf.substr(0, recvbuf.find('0x0D', 0));
    printf("Message after slicing: %s\n", msg);
}
```

The output is this:

```
Message received: jess╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠°÷u
Message as string: ╪≥u
Message is exactly: ┤≥u
```

How can I extract `jess` from the initial array and convert it to a string?

Comment: @thibsc I don't know but I'l try to find out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, it seems the buffer is not null-terminated, so you should use

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              size_type count,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

to initialize string with specifying size.

Secondly, the string initialization cannot access the buffer because the name collides.

Thirdly, `%s` won't accept `std::string`.

Also note that you can specify length to print dynamically by using `%.*s` format specifier.

```
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

int iResult = recv(this->ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
if (iResult > 0) {
    printf("Message received: %.*s\n", iResult, recvbuf);
    std::string recvbuf2(recvbuf, iResult);
    printf("Message as string: %s\n", recvbuf2.c_str());
    std::string msg = recvbuf2.substr(0, recvbuf2.find('0x0D', 0));
    printf("Message after slicing: %s\n", msg.c_str());
}
```

(Note: `'0x0D'` is multi-character character literal and its value is implementation-defined)

Comment: Also worth remembering that `recv` provides what it has available or, if no data is available, blocks until data becomes available. It makes no guarantees you get all of what you expect. For example with a TCP socket, the data comes in a stream and `recv` will read up to `DEFAULT_BUFLEN` bytes from that stream. You could receive only part of "Jess" or far more than just "Jess". With a UDP socket you get discrete messages,so a message that contains "Jess" is either all there or not there, but you get no delivery or ordering guarantees.